# AngularJS update single model in ng-repeat after http

Tags: php, angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code for an application, which loads data from http.

Initial json-data:

```
"phasen": {
    "item1": false,
    "item2": [{
        "phasen_id": "1",
        "phasen_group_id": "2",
        "phasen_group_name": "groupx",
        "phasen_name": "name1",
        "phasen_data": {
            "phasen_status": "1",
            "user_modified_id": "10",
            "user_modified_name": "Admin  ",
            "createdate": "17.06.2016 | 10:19"
        }
    }, {
        "phasen_id": "2",
        "phasen_group_id": "2",
        "phasen_group_name": "name2",
        "phasen_data": false
    }, {
        "phasen_id": "3",
        "phasen_group_id": "2",
        "phasen_group_name": "name3",
        "phasen_data": false
    }
    ]
}
```

html-code:

```
<div ng-repeat="myData in dataSet.phasen.item2">

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" ng-checked="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status == '1'" ng-change="savedata('{{myData.phasen_group_id}}','{{myData.phasen_id}}', myData.phasen_data.phasen_status)" icheck />
    </div>

    <div class="info-box-content">
        <span class="info-box-text">{{myData.phasen_name}}</span>
        <span class="info-box-number">
            <div ng-show="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status == '1'" class="small">{{myData.phasen_data.createdate}}  |  {{myData.phasen_data.user_modified_name}}</div>
        </span>                         
    </div>  

</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$scope.savedata = function(phasen_group_id, phasen_id, phasen_status){

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: base_url + "dataapi/savedata/",
        data: { 'phasen_group_id': phasen_group_id, 'phasen_id': phasen_id, 'phasen_status': phasen_status},
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        var data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
        $parse('dataSet.phasen').assign($scope, data);  
    });

};
```

Is it possible to save the data and to update only one item in ng-repeat with the response data from http?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Just pass whole single object to the savedata function.
In your case it is `ng-repeat="myData in dataSet.phasen.item2"` so you need to pass mydata.

```
savedata(myData);
```

In success just assign response object to the myData and it will be automatically updated in the view because when you pass whole object from the ng-repeat it is passed by reference, not by value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div ng-repeat="myData in dataSet.phasen.item2">

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" ng-checked="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status == '1'" ng-change="savedata(myData)" icheck />
</div>

<div class="info-box-content">
    <span class="info-box-text">{{myData.phasen_name}}</span>
    <span class="info-box-number">
        <div ng-show="myData.phasen_data.phasen_status == '1'" class="small">{{myData.phasen_data.createdate}}  |  {{myData.phasen_data.user_modified_name}}</div>
    </span>                         
</div>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
$scope.savedata = function(myData){

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: base_url + "dataapi/savedata/",
    data: myData
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
}).then(function(response){
    var data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
    $parse('dataSet.phasen').assign($scope, data);  
});
```

};